# Ansible Variable precedence - what are 'role params' & 'include params'

Tags: ansible

The Ansible documentation has a list of [Variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

Some of them are clear to me but I wonder whether anybody coulde kinkdy shed some light on those 2.

> 20. **role (and include_role) params**
> 21. **include params**

usage, location, syntax.

I am trying to get Variable declaration a little further to the surface inside a little more complex playbook utilizing 2 roles I am currently working on.

concrete ... some values inside task files of a role should rather be declared as variables in a single location.

Comment: See [include params from the list of variable precedence list has no examples #95](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-documentation/issues/95).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell examples:

## role params

(full playbook)

```yaml
- name: I'm a dummy play
  hosts: localhost

  roles:
    - role: somerole
      vars:
        param1: "I'm a role param"
```

## Include role params

(task only)

```yaml
- name: Including role somerole
  ansible.builtin.include_role:
    name: somerole
  vars:
    param1: "I'm an include role param"
```

## Include params

(task only)

```yaml
- name: Including a task file
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: sometasks.yaml
  vars:
    param1: "I'm an include param"
```

---

As a fictive and (most probably bad practice) example: if you include a role passing a parameter and later include a task file in that role passing that same parameter with a different value, the include param will take precedence over the role param.

Comment: what about 17. task vars (only for the task). https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable:~:text=task%20vars%20(only%20for%20the%20task)

Comment: @capa_matrix is this a question? If yes, comments are the wrong place to ask. Please hit the "ask a question" button on top of the page. But as a clue, 17 is lower than 20 and 21 and on that doc, highest wins. This is very easy to test directly on your side. Just craft an example.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! So I did some experiments and confirmed some things but was still left confused so made a question. If you know are able able to look, it would be greatly appreciated :D - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77108484/ansible-variable-scope-and-precedence-what-is-the-scope-of-vars-defined-varia